# FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to read the JSON using Alamofire. Here is my code:

```
    let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]

    func getConfirmationCode(params: [String:Any], block: @escaping(_ data : JSON, _ success : Bool) -> Void) {
    if let url = URL(string: baseURL + "getConfirmationCode.php") {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    block(json, true)
                } else {
                    block(JSON.null, false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON is valid, everything works perfectly in Postman, but I can't make it work. None of the suggestions on the web helped (changing the responseJSON to responseString/responseData, changing the JSONEncoding.default to URLEncoding.default, etc.)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you compared your Postman and in app request?

Comment: @Emma, I am also facing the same issue, Do you find any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check response in postman in "Preview" tab of response section. sometime it displays proper json in "Pretty" section. but in "Preview" section it many contains some print statements of API response. and those print statements makes problem in json decoding.

[image]

also, if you want to get swift code of postman response you can always get it from postman's code feature:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps..!